# How to not infer schema while creating dataframe from json?

Tags: python, json, apache-spark, pyspark

I don't want infer schema while creating dataframe from a group of jsons, but I can not pass `inferSchema = 'false'` like when I read from csv. Here is how I read the data:

```
df = spark.read.json(r's3://mypath/')
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After looking for a while, I found in the [docs](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.0.2/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/DataFrameReader.html#json(org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDD)) that I can use the parameter 'primitivesAsString'

```
df = spark.read.json(r's3://mypath/', primitivesAsString='true')
```

This way I can forbid inference at least for primite types. But, I will not avoid it for arrays and structs. Still, it works to me.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of infering the schema, you can create it yourself and then tell Spark to use it. Small example with 3 columns of different types:

```
schema = StructType([StructField('name', StringType(), True),
                     StructField('datetime', TimestampType(), True)
                     StructField('age', IntegerType(), True)])

df = spark.read.schema(schema).json(r's3://mypath/')
```

This will only work if you know the structure of the JSON files in advance. However, if there are multiple files with different structures they can be merged together by reading with the same schema. The files that does not have some of the columns will simply have `null` values for those.

Comment: The problem with this is that I don't know what to expect, I mean, I don't know the name of the columns from the json.

Comment: @Ifvv: Yes, this only works if you know which columns you want to use. If the json files contains different columns that are of interest, all can be specified in the same schema. For the ones missing columns the value will be null.